# concatenate all strings in the dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert all the strings in a dataframe column as a single empty string and then convert it in to list of words:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'read': ["Red", "is", "my", "favorite", "color"]})
print(df)
    read
0   Red
1   is
2   my
3   favorite
4   color
```

I tried to join strings but I don't know how to add space.

```
string = ""
for i,j in df.iterrows():
    string += j["read"]
```

Output:

```
'Redismyfavoritecolor'
```

Required Output:

```
"Red is my favorite color"
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use `join` with whitespace:

```
out = ' '.join(df["read"])
print (out)
Red is my favorite color
```

Comment: I am getting a type error when I try it in my dataframe. It's says expected str instance but got float. How can I fix it?

Comment: @sai_636 - How working `' '.join(df["read"].astype(str))` or `' '.join(df["read"].dropna())` if `float` values are `NaN`s

Comment: This code  ' '.join(df["read"].astype(str)) this fixed it. Does this line convert all values to string before joining?

Comment: @sai_636 exactly, it convert values to string.